# Listagg to get certain values in string and leave other values seperate

Tags: sql, oracle, join, listagg

I'm trying to get some values from a table into a string and want to leave some out. A different column would determine which values I want in the string and which ones I want to leave out of the string.

The table (table2) I'm using for the string:

| t_id | attribute | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1123 | a | 4rt |
| 1123 | a | 8nf |
| 1123 | b | 9sa |
| 1123 | c | 8sf |
| 1123 | d | 6df |
| 1123 | b | 3er |
| 1231 | a | 8nf |
| 1231 | b | 3fg |
| 1231 | d | 6ty |
| 1231 | c | 4rg |
| 1231 | b | 0rg |

The query I used to get the full string for every t_id in the table:

```
select distinct t0.*, t3.pool,

listagg(distinct t1.code ,',) within group(order by t1.t_id)
over (partition by t1.t_id) as "CODES"

from table1 t0

left join table2 t1
on t0.id = t1.t_id

left join table3 t2
on t0.id = t2.t_id

left join table4 t3
on t0_id = t3.t_id

where t0.active = '1'
and t2.someother_id = '123456789'
```

What I need is something where I can get a string for all codes from table2 where attribute = a and b and I would need attribute c and d seperate like:

| t_id | attribute | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1123 | a,b | 4rt, 8nf, 9sa, 3er |
| 1123 | c | 8sf |
| 1123 | d | 6df |
| 1231 | a,b | 8nf, 3fg, 0rg |
| 1231 | c | 4rg |
| 1231 | d | 6ty |

Comment: As the syntax highlighting shows, you are missing a closing `'` for the second argument to `LISTAGG`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `DISTINCT` and analytic functions, use aggregation when you `JOIN` to `table2` and a `CASE` expression in the `GROUP BY` clause so that `a` and `b` values are in the same group:

```sql
SELECT t1.*,
       t4.pool,
       t2.codes
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT t_id,
                LISTAGG(DISTINCT code, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t_id)
                  AS codes
         FROM   table2
         GROUP BY t_id,
                  CASE
                  WHEN attribute IN ('a', 'b')
                  THEN 'a, b'
                  ELSE attribute
                  END
       ) t2
       ON t1.id = t2.t_id
       INNER JOIN table3 t3
       ON t1.id = t3.t_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 t3
       ON t1.id = t4.t_id
WHERE  t1.active = '1'
AND    t3.someother_id = '123456789'
```

*Note: Do not have tables called `table1`, `table2`, etc. and give them aliases `t0`, `t1`, etc. as it is unnecessarily confusing. Use aliases that relate to your table names such as `t1`, `t2`, etc.*

*Note: The `WHERE` clause changes `table3` from being `LEFT OUTER JOIN`ed to `INNER JOIN`ed as the `t3.someother_id = '123456789'` filter will never be true when the table is `OUTER` joined.*

---

If you want to include the `attributes` then depending on what you want to display:

If you want to always display `a, b` even if only `a` or `b` is present then:

```sql
SELECT t1.*,
       t4.pool,
       t2.attributes,
       t2.codes
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT t_id,
                CASE
                WHEN attribute IN ('a', 'b')
                THEN 'a, b'
                ELSE attribute
                END AS attributes,
                LISTAGG(DISTINCT code, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t_id)
                  AS codes
         FROM   table2
         GROUP BY t_id,
                  CASE
                  WHEN attribute IN ('a', 'b')
                  THEN 'a, b'
                  ELSE attribute
                  END
       ) t2
       ON t1.id = t2.t_id
       INNER JOIN table3 t3
       ON t1.id = t3.t_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 t3
       ON t1.id = t4.t_id
WHERE  t1.active = '1'
AND    t3.someother_id = '123456789'
```

or, if you want to display `a`, `b` or `a, b` depending on what is in the table then:

```sql
SELECT t1.*,
       t4.pool,
       t2.attributes,
       t2.codes
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT t_id,
                LISTAGG(DISTINCT attribute, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY attribute)
                  AS attributes,
                LISTAGG(DISTINCT code, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t_id)
                  AS codes
         FROM   table2
         GROUP BY t_id,
                  CASE
                  WHEN attribute IN ('a', 'b')
                  THEN 'a, b'
                  ELSE attribute
                  END
       ) t2
       ON t1.id = t2.t_id
       INNER JOIN table3 t3
       ON t1.id = t3.t_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 t3
       ON t1.id = t4.t_id
WHERE  t1.active = '1'
AND    t3.someother_id = '123456789'
```

or, if you want a list that has attributes that correspond to the `code` values (so may contain multiple `a` or `b` values):

```sql
SELECT t1.*,
       t4.pool,
       t2.attributes,
       t2.codes
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT t_id,
                LISTAGG(attribute, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t_id)
                  AS attributes,
                LISTAGG(code, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t_id)
                  AS codes
         FROM   (
           SELECT DISTINCT
                  t_id,
                  attribute,
                  code
           FROM   table2
         )
         GROUP BY t_id,
                  CASE
                  WHEN attribute IN ('a', 'b')
                  THEN 'a, b'
                  ELSE attribute
                  END
       ) t2
       ON t1.id = t2.t_id
       INNER JOIN table3 t3
       ON t1.id = t3.t_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 t3
       ON t1.id = t4.t_id
WHERE  t1.active = '1'
AND    t3.someother_id = '123456789'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I would ideally also have the attribute column in my results as some kind of string. I would need another LISTAGG in the query I think, but I'm getting error so far

Comment: @Lvh Updated with several options.